# Saving a game state to a file

Tags: java, file-io, libgdx, kryo

I'm now at a point where I need to save the current game state.
I'm using libGDX and did add the kryo lib to my project and did some testings.

Question:

- Do I have to override the file every save or can I override only the bites that change from one class.
- Do I have to create allways a new OutputStream if I whant the game to be saved? (Save game every 5 mins for example)
- I whant the current entities that are created to be saved should I create one file for all or for each entity a file?

Answer (score 0):

Dario,

> Do I have to override the file every save or can I override only the
>   bites that change from one class.

You don't have to, but should (create a fresh save file on every save). There is no reason to overcomplicate this.

> Do I have to create allways a new OutputStream if I whant the game to
>   be saved? (Save game every 5 mins for example)

Again, why worry? You save once per 5 minutes, you won't notice any difference (besides your coding time and efforts being wasted) if you reused your OutputStream or created a new one. Create a new one.

> I whant the current entities that are created to be saved should I
>   create one file for all or for each entity a file?

Depends on what makes sense and what these "entities" are. In any case to save the entity you will need to serialize it, which is just a fancy way of saying create a representation of it in text. To load the entity, reverse the process (deserialize it). The easiest way to learn how to do this is to make a JSONObject ([library here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212)). Put the values from the entity into the JSONObject and to turn it into text, call JSONObject.toString(). To deserialize it, create a new JSONObject and pass the text into its constructor. You may then retrieve the values.

Comment: These entities could be 3 types: Enemies max 15, Projectiles max 50, Blocks (Triangles that are destructable but grow back after time ) They have to grow back allso if they're not in the vilible area (only visible areas of the map will be loaded)

Comment: Save it into 1 file as described.